# Storing data in reverse order in an array based list efficiently

Tags: java, data-structures

Hi I have a data structures programming project involving creating my own array based list and then efficiently storing String read from a file but in reverse.
So that arr[0] = the last line of the file

Initially I just thought to have two for loops:
First to store the data by its order in my list
Second to create a new list and add elements in reverse order

Then I thought about just creating an array based list that stores data in reverse, so that the first line of the file is stored at arr[arr.length-1] and so on. This I believe is saving me a for loop

I know in the end both are O(n), but is this what my professor means when he says "as efficient as possible"?

Are there any other ways I could reverse my list?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't say what your professor means when he say "as efficient as possible". In term of performance ? Of memory consumption ? Ask him first for that.

Comment: It helps if you have some code you have already created to solve the problem. At this point (design), there is a lot of good choices that can be made, and since this is an assignment, we also don't know the constraints on what you can use (generics, streams, etc) to make useful suggestions. Based on array and file, read the file into an array, then reverse the array (walk the array, swapping(arr[i], arr[length - i]). O(n) time, O(n) space where n is the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Is there something wrong with developing a class that stores the contents in an array in forward order and retrieving elements in reverse by calculating an element number relative to the end?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a list? Storing the data in a reverse order sounds to me like a situation where a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) should be used.

You could implement a stack and just push every row on top of it. Then, when you pop every element of the top of the stack, they would be popped in the reverse order.

Considering that this is a data structures programming project, it might be what your professor would like to see.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on constraint for given problem.You can get the number of lines from given file. If length is n.
You can fill arraylist in reverse order. or
You can create list with original order.
Then try reversing created list.

Comment: How would you get the number of lines from the file efficiently? AFAIK on *nixes, usually you need to read the entire file to count the number of lines, which would be slower than OP's current solution of reading all the lines first and reversing them in memory since two reads of the entire file will take up a lot more I/O time. But maybe there's a way to do that efficiently that I don't know about!

Answer (score 0):

> Then I thought about just creating an array based list that stores data in reverse, so that the first line of the file is stored at arr[arr.length-1] and so on. This I believe is saving me a for loop

Yup, it does, and I think this is probably the most efficient way to do this! Remember that your array-based list doesn't have to know how many items will eventually be added to it: when someone calls yourArrayList.get(2), you can return the last item currently in your list (i.e. `array.length-2-1`).

I think your professor meant both computational complexity (i.e. `O(n)`) as well as taking the least amount of time. One loop will take less time than two!